# How to measure the difference between two frames given a set of pixel units for each frame?

Tags: opticalflow

I am using a dense optical flow algorithm in order to calculate the optical flow on a given video,
after I run the algorithm I receive the output bellow.

I would like to find a way to sum up the changes between two frames (or two sets of vectors (in pixel units)), meaning to find a numerical value to the change between frames in order to determine if these two frames are "similar" or "different"

this is the output (from what I understand, for each pixel it is the change x, y basically):

```
flow
[[[ 0.00080293  0.00456178]
  [ 0.0023454   0.00762859]
  [ 0.00337119  0.01088941]
  ...
  [ 0.08646814  0.17195833]
  [ 0.07680464  0.15070145]
  [ 0.04990056  0.09711792]]

 [[ 0.00197109  0.00610898]
  [ 0.00431191  0.01074001]
  [ 0.00629149  0.01567514]
  ...
  [ 0.11541913  0.23083425]
  [ 0.10006026  0.19827926]
  [ 0.06407876  0.12646647]]

 [[ 0.00333168  0.0071025 ]
  [ 0.00625938  0.01281219]
  [ 0.01047979  0.02093185]
  ...
  [ 0.15598673  0.31461456]
  [ 0.1284331   0.25725985]
  [ 0.08006614  0.16013806]]

 ...

 [[-0.11634359  0.09029744]
  [-0.14934781  0.11287674]
  [-0.24678642  0.17862432]
  ...
  [ 0.00260158  0.00103487]
  [ 0.00391656  0.00041338]
  [ 0.00312206  0.00064316]]

 [[-0.06021533  0.04847184]
  [-0.07352059  0.05851178]
  [-0.12553327  0.09319763]
  ...
  [ 0.00314228 -0.00119414]
  [ 0.00410303 -0.00139949]
  [ 0.00334636 -0.00098234]]

 [[-0.0192373   0.010998  ]
  [-0.02326458  0.01555626]
  [-0.04161371  0.02764582]
  ...
  [ 0.00236979 -0.00039244]
  [ 0.00327405 -0.00078911]
  [ 0.00281549 -0.00057979]]]
flow
[[[-8.4514404e-03 -9.1092577e-03]
  [-8.2096420e-03 -1.6217180e-02]
  [-9.7641135e-03 -2.3235001e-02]
  ...
  [ 8.4836602e-02  9.4629139e-02]
  [ 7.0593305e-02  7.2248474e-02]
  [ 6.2410351e-02  5.8204494e-02]]

 [[-1.6573617e-02 -1.5174728e-02]
  [-1.5833536e-02 -2.2253623e-02]
  [-1.7538801e-02 -3.1138226e-02]
  ...
  [ 1.3201687e-01  1.3085920e-01]
  [ 1.1270510e-01  1.0012541e-01]
  [ 1.0345179e-01  8.3722569e-02]]

 [[-2.1787306e-02 -2.0292744e-02]
  [-2.2391599e-02 -2.8152039e-02]
  [-2.3549989e-02 -3.8980592e-02]
  ...
  [ 1.5739001e-01  1.6933599e-01]
  [ 1.3471533e-01  1.2855931e-01]
  [ 1.2196152e-01  1.0327549e-01]]

 ...

 [[-3.9006339e-03 -3.0767643e-03]
  [-1.8084457e-02 -8.7532159e-03]
  [-4.0460575e-02 -1.6521217e-02]
  ...
  [ 5.4473747e-03 -1.9708525e-03]
  [ 4.3195980e-03 -1.6532388e-03]
  [ 2.4038905e-03 -2.6415614e-04]]

 [[-2.2322503e-03 -3.0169063e-03]
  [-1.1787469e-02 -8.9037549e-03]
  [-2.8192652e-02 -1.6921449e-02]
  ...
  [ 1.9799198e-03 -3.8150212e-04]
  [ 1.5747466e-03 -5.4049061e-04]
  [ 9.2306529e-04 -1.1204407e-04]]

 [[-1.1798806e-03 -1.9108414e-03]
  [-6.6612735e-03 -5.3157108e-03]
  [-1.6056010e-02 -9.3358066e-03]
  ...
  [ 4.8137631e-04  6.4036541e-04]
  [ 3.4130082e-04  3.7227676e-04]
  [ 1.7955518e-04  1.8480681e-04]]]...
```

this id the code we are using for the optical flow calculation:

```
def _calc_optical_flow_(distance_array):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture("videos/3.1.avi")
    output_file_text = open("output.txt", "w+")

    ret, frame1 = cap.read()
    prvs = cv2.cvtColor(frame1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    hsv = np.zeros_like(frame1)
    frames_array.append(frame1)

    hsv[..., 1] = 255
    count = 0
    distance = 0


    while(1):
        ret, frame2 = cap.read()
        if frame2 is None:
            break
        frames_array.append(frame2)
        next = cv2.cvtColor(frame2,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        flow = cv2.calcOpticalFlowFarneback(prvs, next, None, pyr_scale=0.5, levels=3, winsize=15, iterations=1,
                                            poly_n=5, poly_sigma=1.2, flags=0)
        mag, ang = cv2.cartToPolar(flow[..., 0], flow[..., 1])

        hsv[..., 0] = ang*180/np.pi/2
        hsv[..., 2] = cv2.normalize(mag, None, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
        rgb = cv2.cvtColor(hsv, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
        if count == 10:
            count = 0

            output_file_text.write("flow\n")
            output_file_text.write(np.array_str(flow) + "\n")
            distance = function(flow, distance)
            distance_array.append(distance)
            #print ("flow",flow)

        cv2.imshow('frame2',rgb)
        count=count+1
        k = cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xff
        if k == 27:
            break
        elif k == ord('s'):
            #cv2.imwrite('opticalfb.png', frame2)
            #cv2.imwrite('opticalhsv.png', rgb)
            prvs = next

    output_file_text.close()
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    return distance_array
```

Comment: What language are you using to evaluate the optical flow? Or are you just looking for general guidance for how to analyze the difference based on these data?

Comment: We are using Python, the code is pretty similar to OpenCV, I will put it in the question

Comment: Are you looking for a global or local measure? I would suggest to use some statistics of the magnitude field from your flow field e.g. the average (mean) or median. Since magnitude is the length of the motion vectors, if there is no change between two frame the length should be zero. However, you may need to filter outliers which came from errors made by the optical flow method (at homogenious areas)